# Python skipping my if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, output

For some reason, this code doesn't work:

```
def pyglatin(word):
    output = ""
    wordlenedit = len(word)-1
    wordlen = len(word)
    fixer = 0
    while fixer == 0:
        for i in word:
            if i == 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'o' or i == 'i' or i == 'u':
                fixer = 1
            else:
                wordlenedit -= 1
    else:
        output = word[wordlenedit:wordlen:1] + '-' + word[0:wordlenedit:1] + 'ay'
        return output
```

To see the issues, click [here](http://labs.codecademy.com/BTk9/2#%3aworkspace). The problem appears to be that it's skipping the *if* statement that identifies vowels, but I'm not sure why. This results in some very odd outputs.

Comment: FYI, your link does not work.

Comment: adding a simple print statement in that block shows it's working.  Not that you should write it like that; use `if i in 'aeiou':`.

Comment: Works for me - `print pyglatin("hello")` results in "ello-hay".  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  And what makes you think python is skipping your if statement?

Comment: Rather than linking externally, can you paste in some test cases which you don't think are working correctly?

Comment: @roppi is right, but I'd also suggest the asker uses a different loop variable too. `if i in 'aeiou'` just looks wrong. I mean `i` is always in `aeiou` right?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr `i` != `'i'`, but you are right, `letter` would be a better variable name.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this function? What is the expected output?

Comment: @glglgl Oh I know, but just at first glance it just seems strange.

Comment: @Brionius Some words work, caused by a fluke in the function, but if you try most longer words they don't.

Comment: @Chet Here are some examples:
"hello" = "ello-hay";
"hallucination" = "cination-halluay";
"monty" = "monty-ay"

Comment: @ThierryJ. I'm trying to achieve proper pig latin. In other words, I'm trying to get it to loop through the word until it hits the vowel, then print the part of the word from before the vowel after the part of the word after the vowel, separated by a dash and followed by an "ay". This would put out "ello-hay" to "hello", "eetings-gray" to "greetings", etc.

Comment: @roppi Thank you for the improved syntax, but it makes no difference towards output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not work because you walk through the word, decrementing the splitting index for each consonant you encounter, starting at `wordlenedit = len(word)-1`.

At the end of your `for` loop, `wordlenedit` is equal to `(length of the word) - 1 - (number of consonants)`. The function will only work if the first index of vowel in the word (starting at 0) is equal to the number of vowels - 1.

Also, the `while` loop is useless here, as you walk through the entire word in the `for` loop. It is even worse than that: the `while` loop will be an infinite loop if you have a word with no vowels (like "fly", as you don't check the "y")

This is a corrected version of your function, using the keyword [break](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
def pyglatin2(word):
    output = ""
    wordlenedit = 0
    wordlen = len(word)
    for l in word:
        if l == 'a' or l == 'e' or l == 'o' or l == 'i' or l == 'u':
            break
        else:
            wordlenedit += 1

    output = word[wordlenedit:wordlen:1] + '-' + word[0:wordlenedit:1] + 'ay'
    return output
```

However this function can be written in a much more concise/simple way, using [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), like this:

```
import re
def pyglatin3(word):
    # Get the first index of one of these: a, e, i, o, u
    start = re.search("[aeiou]", word).start()

    # Split the word
    return word[start:] + "-" + word[0:start] + "ay"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned Python from Codecademy.com, so I don't know more than the basics. Didn't even know regular expressions existed. :p Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using regular expressions, the simplest way is to use  `enumerate`:

```
def pyglatin(word):
    for i, ch in enumerate(word):
        if ch in 'aeiou':
            return word[i:] + '-' + word[:i] + 'ay'
```